# Why it is possible to use a split filter in ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

It might look like a weird question by, I really would like to understand this. I am new to Ansible, and I am trying to understand how I could figure out that I can use a filter called `split`. As I understand, the Ansible filters are builtin inside Jinja2 engine. On the project website there is nothing about `split` filter. I am really confused how come, it is possible to use `split` filter.

On Ansible website there is one mention about `split`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

> To split a string into a list:
>
> ```
> {{ csv_string | split(",") }}
> ```

My question here is, how would I know that I can do `| split(",",1)`
that [page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) does not explain that for example I could call a split filter with delimeter and a integer that describes how many times I want to split it.

Is there a different documentation, or a way to figure those things out on my own?

I was told that I could do in Python:

```py
help(str.split)
```

And this explains me how to use split method, this is great however, how can I be sure that this is the same way of implementation as in the Ansible filter? Is this split filter from Ansible documentation inside 'Ansible' or inside Jinja? And maybe its just missing from documentation in Jinja website?

Comment: Ansible comes with a set of extra Jinja filters, in which, Ansible recently added the `split` filter. You can find all those additional filter on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: Also mind that Ansible extends Jinja by providing a set of extra tests: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't explain where `| split(",")` is coming from but per the Jinja docs:

**[Python Methods](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#python-methods)**

You can also use any of the methods defined on a variable’s type. The value returned from the method invocation is used as the value of the expression. Here is an example that uses methods defined on strings (where page.title is a string):

```
{{ page.title.capitalize() }}
```

So `str.split()` should also be valid syntax and work the same way.

Comment: Thank you Terry, does that also mean that i will be able to use this filter in this case 'capitalize' in my ansible playbook yaml file such as : msg: " testing {{ page.title | capitalize }} " Or is that just when i am inside a template file so i can call var.capitalize ?
I did a try and it looks that i can call those methods in both ways:
msg: "now capitalized {{ dane | capitalize }}"
and
msg: "now capitalized {{ dane.capitalize()}}"
so as such, is it ok to say that this is the same filter ? which is essentially a method coming from the variable class ?

Comment: My guess is the documentation is a little behind the source code.
The split filter looks like it was added [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73532)

And you can see that the filters are implemented as Python functions/partials [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L571) in the source code.

Comment: Thank you Terry, one more question, so now it looks that split is a 'real' filter defined in core.py and it was defined as 'split': partial(unicode_wrap, text_type.split), , if i understand correctly. So what happens when object has already a method called obj.method24 , and somebody makes a filter in ansible called method24, who takes precedence ? 
obj.method24() comes from the real object method
obj | method24 comes from the ansible plugin defined filter?
so a string object has already a method .split , why did somebody create a filter 'split' for ansible , the string obj already has it

Comment: from a user perspective, how can i know if i am calling an ansible filter called 'split' or maybe i am calling a 'string' object method 'split', how can i be sure which one am i using ?

Comment: There's essentially 3 layers of [filter-plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/filter.html#filter-plugins)  

1. standard filters shipped with Jinja2  
2. Ansible specialized filter plugins implemented in `core.py`  
3. custom filters that you would define  

I guess it would be up to the user/developer to prevent a "name collision"? And I'm not sure if it would error if one occurred OR if there's some sort of precedence?