# Ansible - How to do integer comparison in a conditional?

Tags: regex, ansible, conditional-statements

I am trying to do a simple integer comparison in a conditional but something is up, and it is not evaluating properly.

Code within playbook:

```yaml
     - name: Check the version of the current sql database on both dispatchers and save that value.
       command: /usr/bin/mysql -V
       changed_when: false
       register: sqlversion

     - name: Print to the screen the current sql database version.
       debug:
         var: "{{ sqlversion.stdout.split()[4] | regex_search('[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+') | replace(\".\",'') }}"
       register: w

     - name: Show the value of the variable.
       debug:
         var: w

     - name: Test result
       command: w
       when: ( w | int < 55 )
```

The output of the command module (ultimately to get the 5.5 part of the 5.5.43 number:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

My actual run in which the Test result task "fails" as in it runs when it should not, because of the evaluation problem:

```yaml
TASK [Check the version of the current sql database on both dispatchers and save that value.] ***********
ok: [server2]
ok: [server1]

TASK [Print to the screen the current sql database version.] ********************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "55": "55"
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "55": "55"
}

TASK [Show the value of the variable.] ******************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "w": {
        "55": "55",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "w": {
        "55": "55",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}

TASK [Test result] **************************************************************************************
changed: [server1]
changed: [server2]
```

This is not right or expected, clearly the last task shows "changed" in that it ran, and evaluated the condition as true when it shouldn't be.  Instead with how I coded the conditional, it should be skipped instead!  Additionally, if I take away the " | int" then it always skips no matter what the number(s) are.

What's the issue here?  There's got to be a way to make this work.

Comment: Note the dot must be escaped, `'[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+'`

Comment: Understood, and fixed that, but no change with the underlying problem.

Comment: Do not register `w`. Put the declaration into the vars. See below. Then, the condition should work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the parsing

```yaml
w: "{{ sqlversion.stdout|split(',')|first|split()|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
w: 5.5.43
```

Use the test *version*. See [Comparing versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Version is lower than 5.6
      when: w is version('5.6', '<')
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sqlversion:
      stdout: "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.2"
    w: "{{ sqlversion.stdout|split(',')|first|split()|last }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: w
    - debug:
        msg: Version is lower than 5.6
      when: w is version('5.6', '<')
```

---

If the filter [*split*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) is not available use the method twice

```yaml
w: "{{ (sqlversion.stdout.split(',')|first).split()|last }}"
```

Comment: Vladimir, I tried to implement this, but I got an error right during my debug print of the variable:  

fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'. String: {{ sqlversion|split(',')|first|split()|last }}"}

Not sure if it matters, but I also am forced on this series of machines to use ansible 2.9. I know split must exist as a filter because I used it in my own example, so not sure why it's complaining.

Comment: If the filter *split* is not available use the method twice. I added an example. The filter *split* is available since 2.11

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman sir, when using the code from the line because the split filter is not available, it now gives me the results and comparisons that I expected.  This is the answer for people forced into older Ansible version usage.

Answer (score 1):

> *... but I also am forced on this series of machines to use Ansible 2.9 ...*

As mentioned by [Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/)

> *If the filter split is not available use the method twice. I added an example. The filter split is available since 2.11*

the `split` filter for [manipulation strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) is available as of Ansible v2.11 but you can just [use the Python method `.split()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964799/6771046).

As a workround in Ansible v2.9 or 2.10 one could also implement a [Custom Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins) and so [a simple Ansible Jinja2 filter to split a string into a list](https://github.com/timraasveld/ansible-string-split-filter). By doing this a filter like `| split()` can made be available in older versions.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will definitely keep it in mind.